# Test First ruby Rspec Error

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

```
ruby 2.0.0p247
Rails 4.1.4
rspec 3.0.2
```

I'm trying to work on the Test First ruby exercises and am getting error messages when executing rake. or rspec.

Here it is:

```
/Users/ching/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
```

Then some directories, then this at the end:

```
/Users/ching/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby -S rspec /Users/ching/testruby/00_hello/hello_spec.rb -I/Users/ching/testruby/00_hello -I/Users/ching/testruby/00_hello/solution -f documentation -r ./rspec_config failed
```

Comment: Do you have a `spec_helper.rb` in the proper location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rspec 3.0 uses `rails_helper` now instead of `spec_helper`. Replace any `require 'spec_helper'` lines at the top of your specs with `require 'rails_helper'`.